Telegram-bot не отвечает на сообщения
Токен указан правильный я проверял.
Код:
import random, time, telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot('тут токен')

bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message): 
    if message.text == "g":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "g")
        if message.text == "p":
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "p")
        else:
            print("aaaaaaa")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "помощи пока нет я не знаю что сюда писать")
    else:
        pass

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)

Бот не выдаёт ошибку, но при этом не отвечает на сообщения.

@bot.message_handler(.. потеряли @ у декоратора. Вопрос можно закрывать ‍♀️

Вы пропустили @ перед декоратором. Вот правильный код:
import random
import telebot
import time

bot = telebot.TeleBot("тут токен")

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def get_text_messages(message): 
    if message.text == "g":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "g")
    elif message.text == "p":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "p")
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "помощи пока нет я не знаю что сюда писать")
    else:
        print("aaaaaaa")

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)


Спасибо большое
